# Login Failed: You can't use Facebook to log into this app or website because there's an issue with its implementation of Facebook Login

Tags: facebook

Since last few weeks our FB integration is broken, our app and website having option to login using FB, we were pulling FB token and public profile info such as name, email but now seems FB has restricted our app, and got message
"We've restricted this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies."

We double checked updated policies document and it seems nothing is there which can break FB policies, we are struggling to identify exact reason, we raised Appeal few weeks ago to FB but no reply, now we all our live users are stuck they are not able to use their account anymore in our platform.

Is there any way to identify exact reason, based on which parameters FB has blocked our app?

Comment: Did you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, submitted case to FB team, and after few 2 months they activated our app, now apps working fine with FB, noticed that its manual process so sometimes even if app don't have issue such thing can happen.

Comment: How do I submit to activate our app?

Comment: @Almaz you need to "Submit an Appeal" to FB, can submit from  your main FB account.

Answer (score 0):

Finally FB Login started working, as we sent Appeal to FB and they re-activated API Key, explained about data which we are exacting from FB API and use of that data.